# PlayerIO (AS3): How can I tell when a player has disconnected from the network?

Tags: actionscript-3, p2p, multiplayer

I've got a real time game running using the PlayerIO framework. I can easily tell when someone has joined a Room, but I can't tell when someone has left (for example Alt-F4ing the program/browser).

I've considered disconnecting people that are lagging out, but this presents a new set of problems since I'm doing this mostly P2P.

Answer (score 0):

you can know if a player is already disconnected by adding a function or a trace on connection.addMessagehandler("userleft" <-- smething lke that